# who determines the value of "#:abs_g3:main"

Tags: assembly, linker, glibc, arm64

I got a weird bug, and am trying to understand. Particularly, at least, I would like to be sure about which software I should look into: the linker, glibc, assembler, the compiler, or else.

I do know that providing a reduced test case is crucial. However, sorry about not being able to do so. It does not reproduce in x86. It is reproducible on arm64 and a specific Linux distro, which I am not sure if is open to public. I do not yet understand the test case itself well enough to make a reduced test case.

An executable gets a segmentation fault at __libc_start_main. The reason why is in there the control tries to jump to the address effectively kept in a register, x0, which is strangely 0. The x0 is set in the _start function.

```
// in sysdep/aarch64/start.S of glibc
MOVL (0, main)
```

The MOVL macro seems to be defined as follows in sysdep.h in the same directory:

```
# define MOVL(R, NAME)                                  \
    movz    PTR_REG (R), #:abs_g3:NAME;             \
    movk    PTR_REG (R), #:abs_g2_nc:NAME;          \
    movk    PTR_REG (R), #:abs_g1_nc:NAME;          \
    movk    PTR_REG (R), #:abs_g0_nc:NAME;
```

Thus, I guess #:abs_g0_nc:main and the friends are supposed to be some non-zero value but is defined as 0.

So, my question is which component I should blame. The executable is from a Go source code. The Go tool builds a shared library without the help of external linker. Then, Go tool compiles a Go source code, and links it against the Go shared library plus a few other libraries with the external linker, gcc with the gold linker.

I did see _start in start.S is similar with the final executable. Only that the #:abs_g* things are gone. Who replaces the macro(?) with numeric values (0 in this case)?

Does gcc or a compiler already compile _start beforehand, and put the compiled/assembled binary somewhere like /usr/lib{64}? Or, when the linker links altogether, does the linker replace the macro with some numeric value? If the linker does so when the problematic executable is built by linking, what does the linker depend on to calculate the value of #:abs_g0_nc and the friends?

Comment: I guess it is the linker. The only thing it needs for that is the address of `main`. The various `abs_g` just select the appropriate 16 bit part.

Comment: "specific Linux distro, which I am not sure if is open to public." -- it is a violation of GPL to distribute to *you* and *not* distribute to the public.

Comment: Thank you for the comments regarding license! Still, I do not have sufficient knowledge about the test case so that I am not able to make a reduced test case of a handful of lines.

Comment: @Jester Thank you! That’s actually what popped up in my mind. Indeed, using bfd linker instead made the bug go away. The crt1.o looks very much sane to me. So, I guess that it is the linker or the information that the linker expect but I do not know.

Comment: Maybe your linker does not support that type of relocation and instead of producing an error it silently ignores that.

Answer (score 2):

Which component fails?  The main program or the shared object?

`sysdep/aarch64/start.S` should not be linked into a dynamic shared object because it is part of the startup code for the main executable.  Most programs do not have a dynamic symbol for `main`, so binding would fail even if the correct relocations were used.  (The `#:abs_gX` relocations are incompatible with position-independent code required for shared objects.)

If the main program fails, it could be a number of issues.  There really is not enough information in your question to give firm advice.  My guess is some sort of PIE/non-PIE mismatch which leads to the wrong version of the startup code being selected.  Note that `start.S` is assembled multiple times during the glibc build process, with different preprocessor flags, and linked into `crt1.o` (non-PIE/`ET_EXEC` executable), `Scrt1.o` (PIE/`ET_DYN` executable), and `gcrt1.o` (profiling).

Comment: Thank you Florian. I believe the main program fails. The Go tool builds a shared library beforehand, and then builds an executable that is NOT position independent, which is linked against the Go-tool-made shared library and a few more static libraries. Also, thank you so much for the info regarding each .o files!